# REDIS AOF file size continuous doubling

Tags: redis

I have AOF enabled via redis.conf. My AOF file size is growing to double the previous size before a rewrite is triggered. After a couple weeks my little 4.2MB AOF file is allowed to grow to a couple GB before a rewrite is triggered. The issue appears to be that REDIS remembers the file size prior to the rewrite instead of after. Therefore, the file size continues to double. I have confirmed that the persistence property AOF_BASE_SIZE is set to the AOF file size prior to the rewrite each time. Have I miss-configured this? I expect that the AOF file should be rewritten when it reaches 30MB. It currently rewrites to about 4.2MB. Therefore, I would expect it to grow until the minimum 30MB, then rewrite back down to roughly 4.2MB. Instead it follows this pattern: 4.2mb -> 30mb -> 4.2mb -> 60mb -> 4.2mb -> 120mb -> 4.2mb -> 240mb

redis config (5.0.7):

```
appendonly yes
appendfsync everysec
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 30mb
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running 5.0.7? Because 5.0.6 and before do have an issue related to AOF size that was fixed in 5.0.7 - see commit [412eb67](https://github.com/redis/redis/commit/412eb67d21705ca31162d614fb8e3a6a568ef5ed)

Comment: Thanks for the info regarding v5.0.6. Yes, I'm confident I'm running 5.0.7. I will look into the fix though.